# Error connecting to NodeJS Socket Server from Android

Tags: java, android, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I followed the fix in this post: 
[Error connecting an Android Client to a socket server in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541210/error-connecting-an-android-client-to-a-socket-server-in-nodejs)

Had problem connect to socket server nodeJS but the problem is a fix, now the client connecting my log console of nodeJS throw me this:

debug - client authorized
  info  - handshake authorized Qs-he8QJbJYA4zlAw2Yn

But now I get the following errors, please help!

```
02-04 18:34:03.288: W/dalvikvm(2769): Unable to resolve superclass of Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport; (850)
02-04 18:34:03.288: W/dalvikvm(2769): Link of class 'Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;' failed
02-04 18:34:03.292: I/dalvikvm(2769): Could not find method io.socket.WebsocketTransport.create, referenced from method io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport
02-04 18:34:03.292: W/dalvikvm(2769): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5178: Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;.create (Ljava/net/URL;Lio/socket/IOConnection;)Lio/socket/IOTransport;
02-04 18:34:03.292: D/dalvikvm(2769): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x001a
02-04 18:34:03.336: D/libEGL(2769): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-04 18:34:03.336: D/(2769): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9665388, tid 2769
02-04 18:34:03.364: D/libEGL(2769): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-04 18:34:03.364: D/libEGL(2769): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-04 18:34:03.432: W/EGL_genymotion(2769): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-04 18:34:03.436: E/OpenGLRenderer(2769): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-04 18:34:03.452: E/OpenGLRenderer(2769): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-04 18:34:03.452: D/OpenGLRenderer(2769): Enabling debug mode 0
02-04 18:34:03.484: W/dalvikvm(2769): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bfb648)
02-04 18:34:03.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2769): FATAL EXCEPTION: ConnectThread
02-04 18:34:03.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2769): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.socket.WebsocketTransport
02-04 18:34:03.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2769):     at io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport(IOConnection.java:334)
02-04 18:34:03.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2769):     at io.socket.IOConnection.access$2(IOConnection.java:329)
02-04 18:34:03.484: E/AndroidRuntime(2769):     at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:200)
02-04 18:34:55.255: W/EGL_genymotion(2769): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-04 18:35:11.247: W/dalvikvm(2893): Unable to resolve superclass of Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport; (850)
02-04 18:35:11.247: W/dalvikvm(2893): Link of class 'Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;' failed
02-04 18:35:11.247: I/dalvikvm(2893): Could not find method io.socket.WebsocketTransport.create, referenced from method io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport
02-04 18:35:11.251: W/dalvikvm(2893): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5178: Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;.create (Ljava/net/URL;Lio/socket/IOConnection;)Lio/socket/IOTransport;
02-04 18:35:11.251: D/dalvikvm(2893): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x001a
02-04 18:35:11.435: D/libEGL(2893): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-04 18:35:11.435: D/(2893): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb9665448, tid 2893
02-04 18:35:11.447: D/libEGL(2893): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-04 18:35:11.451: D/libEGL(2893): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-04 18:35:11.527: W/EGL_genymotion(2893): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-04 18:35:11.527: E/OpenGLRenderer(2893): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-04 18:35:11.543: E/OpenGLRenderer(2893): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-04 18:35:11.547: D/OpenGLRenderer(2893): Enabling debug mode 0
02-04 18:35:11.999: W/dalvikvm(2893): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bfb648)
02-04 18:35:12.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2893): FATAL EXCEPTION: ConnectThread
02-04 18:35:12.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2893): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.socket.WebsocketTransport
02-04 18:35:12.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport(IOConnection.java:334)
02-04 18:35:12.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at io.socket.IOConnection.access$2(IOConnection.java:329)
02-04 18:35:12.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2893):     at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:200)
02-05 00:00:39.425: W/EGL_genymotion(6554): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-05 00:00:39.429: E/OpenGLRenderer(6554): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-05 00:00:39.449: E/OpenGLRenderer(6554): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-05 00:00:39.449: D/OpenGLRenderer(6554): Enabling debug mode 0
02-05 00:00:39.961: W/dalvikvm(6554): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bd0648)
02-05 00:00:39.961: E/AndroidRuntime(6554): FATAL EXCEPTION: ConnectThread
02-05 00:00:39.961: E/AndroidRuntime(6554): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.socket.WebsocketTransport
02-05 00:00:39.961: E/AndroidRuntime(6554):     at io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport(IOConnection.java:334)
02-05 00:00:39.961: E/AndroidRuntime(6554):     at io.socket.IOConnection.access$2(IOConnection.java:329)
02-05 00:00:39.961: E/AndroidRuntime(6554):     at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:200)
02-05 01:04:19.745: W/dalvikvm(12864): Unable to resolve superclass of Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport; (853)
02-05 01:04:19.745: W/dalvikvm(12864): Link of class 'Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;' failed
02-05 01:04:19.745: I/dalvikvm(12864): Could not find method io.socket.WebsocketTransport.create, referenced from method io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport
02-05 01:04:19.745: W/dalvikvm(12864): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5202: Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;.create (Ljava/net/URL;Lio/socket/IOConnection;)Lio/socket/IOTransport;
02-05 01:04:19.745: D/dalvikvm(12864): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x001a
02-05 01:04:19.861: D/libEGL(12864): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-05 01:04:19.865: D/(12864): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8c1ecc0, tid 12864
02-05 01:04:19.885: D/libEGL(12864): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-05 01:04:19.885: D/libEGL(12864): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-05 01:04:20.029: W/EGL_genymotion(12864): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-05 01:04:20.029: E/OpenGLRenderer(12864): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-05 01:04:20.045: E/OpenGLRenderer(12864): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-05 01:04:20.049: D/OpenGLRenderer(12864): Enabling debug mode 0
02-05 01:04:20.481: W/dalvikvm(12864): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bd0648)
02-05 01:04:20.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12864): FATAL EXCEPTION: ConnectThread
02-05 01:04:20.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12864): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.socket.WebsocketTransport
02-05 01:04:20.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12864):    at io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport(IOConnection.java:334)
02-05 01:04:20.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12864):    at io.socket.IOConnection.access$2(IOConnection.java:329)
02-05 01:04:20.485: E/AndroidRuntime(12864):    at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:200)
02-05 01:06:08.111: W/dalvikvm(13088): Unable to resolve superclass of Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport; (853)
02-05 01:06:08.111: W/dalvikvm(13088): Link of class 'Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;' failed
02-05 01:06:08.111: I/dalvikvm(13088): Could not find method io.socket.WebsocketTransport.create, referenced from method io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport
02-05 01:06:08.111: W/dalvikvm(13088): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5202: Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;.create (Ljava/net/URL;Lio/socket/IOConnection;)Lio/socket/IOTransport;
02-05 01:06:08.111: D/dalvikvm(13088): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x001a
02-05 01:06:08.151: W/dalvikvm(13088): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bd0648)
02-05 01:06:08.151: E/AndroidRuntime(13088): FATAL EXCEPTION: ConnectThread
02-05 01:06:08.151: E/AndroidRuntime(13088): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.socket.WebsocketTransport
02-05 01:06:08.151: E/AndroidRuntime(13088):    at io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport(IOConnection.java:334)
02-05 01:06:08.151: E/AndroidRuntime(13088):    at io.socket.IOConnection.access$2(IOConnection.java:329)
02-05 01:06:08.151: E/AndroidRuntime(13088):    at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:200)
02-05 01:06:08.219: D/libEGL(13088): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-05 01:06:08.219: D/(13088): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8c1e050, tid 13088
02-05 01:06:08.235: D/libEGL(13088): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-05 01:06:08.235: D/libEGL(13088): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-05 01:06:08.315: W/EGL_genymotion(13088): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-05 01:06:08.319: E/OpenGLRenderer(13088): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-05 01:06:08.339: E/OpenGLRenderer(13088): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-05 01:06:08.343: D/OpenGLRenderer(13088): Enabling debug mode 0
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 3000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at chatClientAndroid.com.MainActivity$ClientThread.run(MainActivity.java:64)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-05 01:20:24.017: W/System.err(14400):    ... 6 more
02-05 01:23:53.462: D/libEGL(14885): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-05 01:23:53.470: D/(14885): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8b48100, tid 14885
02-05 01:23:53.482: D/libEGL(14885): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-05 01:23:53.490: D/libEGL(14885): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-05 01:23:53.638: W/EGL_genymotion(14885): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-05 01:23:53.638: E/OpenGLRenderer(14885): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-05 01:23:53.654: E/OpenGLRenderer(14885): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-05 01:23:53.658: D/OpenGLRenderer(14885): Enabling debug mode 0
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 3000): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:566)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:225)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at chatClientAndroid.com.MainActivity$ClientThread.run(MainActivity.java:83)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-05 01:24:56.465: W/System.err(14885):    ... 6 more
02-05 01:26:04.608: D/libEGL(15143): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-05 01:26:04.612: D/(15143): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8c24b68, tid 15143
02-05 01:26:04.620: D/libEGL(15143): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-05 01:26:04.624: D/libEGL(15143): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-05 01:26:04.700: W/EGL_genymotion(15143): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-05 01:26:04.704: E/OpenGLRenderer(15143): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-05 01:26:04.716: E/OpenGLRenderer(15143): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-05 01:26:04.720: D/OpenGLRenderer(15143): Enabling debug mode 0
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324): java.lang.Exception
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at chatClientAndroid.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:47)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-05 01:54:04.627: W/System.err(18324):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-05 01:54:04.639: W/dalvikvm(18324): Unable to resolve superclass of Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport; (853)
02-05 01:54:04.639: W/dalvikvm(18324): Link of class 'Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;' failed
02-05 01:54:04.639: I/dalvikvm(18324): Could not find method io.socket.WebsocketTransport.create, referenced from method io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport
02-05 01:54:04.639: W/dalvikvm(18324): VFY: unable to resolve static method 5202: Lio/socket/WebsocketTransport;.create (Ljava/net/URL;Lio/socket/IOConnection;)Lio/socket/IOTransport;
02-05 01:54:04.639: D/dalvikvm(18324): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x001a
02-05 01:54:04.671: W/dalvikvm(18324): threadid=13: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4bd0648)
02-05 01:54:04.671: E/AndroidRuntime(18324): FATAL EXCEPTION: ConnectThread
02-05 01:54:04.671: E/AndroidRuntime(18324): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.socket.WebsocketTransport
02-05 01:54:04.671: E/AndroidRuntime(18324):    at io.socket.IOConnection.connectTransport(IOConnection.java:334)
02-05 01:54:04.671: E/AndroidRuntime(18324):    at io.socket.IOConnection.access$2(IOConnection.java:329)
02-05 01:54:04.671: E/AndroidRuntime(18324):    at io.socket.IOConnection$ConnectThread.run(IOConnection.java:200)
02-05 01:54:04.787: D/libEGL(18324): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_genymotion.so
02-05 01:54:04.791: D/(18324): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb8c298e0, tid 18324
02-05 01:54:04.807: D/libEGL(18324): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_genymotion.so
02-05 01:54:04.807: D/libEGL(18324): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_genymotion.so
02-05 01:54:04.899: W/EGL_genymotion(18324): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-05 01:54:04.903: E/OpenGLRenderer(18324): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache
02-05 01:54:04.927: E/OpenGLRenderer(18324): Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()
02-05 01:54:04.931: D/OpenGLRenderer(18324): Enabling debug mode 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError...usually it means that in the classpath is missing a derivated dependency. In other words io.socket.WebsocketTransport needs classes which aren't in the classpath. Could this be the problem?